# chrome.tabs.query not showing newly added tabs

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a loop that every 10 seconds gives me the url of my tabs but this one is not refreshed when I add a new tab.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
function initTabs(){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: false, active: false}, function(tabs){
        tabsChrome = tabs;
        checkTabs();
    });
}

function checkTabs(){
    var res = false;
    if(tabsChrome != null){
        for(var i = 0; i < tabsChrome.length; i++){     
            console.log(tabsChrome[i].url)  
            if(tabsChrome[i].url.toLowerCase() == "https://dlive.tv/Teuf".toLowerCase()){
                res = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `currentWindow: false, active: false`

Comment: I suggested removing but you can do anything you want, it's not like I order you around :-)

Comment: thx, its good with remove :)